# How to interact with custom UITableViewCell class?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i created table view with custom UITableViewCell class. So my app should set UIStepper hidden when button in navigation bar is tapped. Than it should update count Label by Stepper's value
My app's mission to see count and list of medicines at your home. So update each medical's count when stepper at that row is tapped.

```
import UIKit
class MedicinesListPage: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    struct Medicine {
        var name: String
        var count: Int
    }
    var medicines = [
        Medicine(name: "Парацетамол", count: 1),
        Medicine(name: "Ибуфен", count: 2),
        Medicine(name: "Цитрамон", count: 1),
        Medicine(name: "Смекта", count: 1),
        Medicine(name: "Мезин", count: 1),
        Medicine(name: "Терафлю", count: 1),
        Medicine(name: "Спирт", count: 1),
        Medicine(name: "Бинт", count: 1),
        Medicine(name: "Мукалтин", count: 1),
        Medicine(name: "Стрепсилс", count: 1)
    ]
    
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action:(#selector(showEditing)))
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
    }
    @objc func showEditing(){
        
// should unhide stepper 
    }
    
    
    


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 65
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return medicines.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "medicalTableViewCell") as? medicalTableViewCell
        cell?.configureCell(name: medicines[indexPath.row].name, count: medicines[indexPath.row].count)
        return cell!
    }
}
```

UITableViewCell class

```
import UIKit

final class medicalTableViewCell: UITableViewCell{
    
 
    
    @IBOutlet weak var medicalName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var medicalCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func stepperTapped(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        // should update count of medicals
    }
    
    
    public func configureCell(name: String, count: Int){
        
        medicalName.text = name
        medicalCount.text = String(count)
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I kind of understood your question but still, it is not clear. Could you show the picture of your view controllers? I just want to see how it 'looks' and is implemented.

Comment: it's like an Notes app. u should make a list of products to buy and update count of them via UIStepper. Product names, count and stepper are in UITableViewCell. My mission is to update count label of product witch are in MedicinesListPage from custom UITableViewCell. i hope u understood me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood, you have a `TableViewController` with customs `UITableView` cells.
Each cell contains medicine name, its number and the `UIStepper` (that allows to change the number of that medicine).
You goal is to update `medicalCountLabel` every time the `UIStepper` is tapped.

(from the conversation in the comments, this is what I implemented)
[image]

Custom UITableViewCell Class

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    //MARK: - Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var countLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    //MARK: - Actions
    
    @IBAction func stepperTapped(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        countLabel.text = Int(sender.value).description
    } //this is where you update `medicalCountLabel`
    
}
```

TableViewController Class:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    //MARK: - Properties
    var medicines = [Medicine(name: "Парацетамол", count: 4), Medicine(name: "Ибуфен", count: 7),Medicine(name: "Цитрамон", count: 4),Medicine(name: "Смекта", count: 9), Medicine(name: "Мезин", count: 2)]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return medicines.count
    }

    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell else{
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of TableViewCell.")
        }

        // Configure the cell
        let medicine = medicines[indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel.text = medicine.name
        cell.countLabel.text = String(medicine.count)
        cell.stepper.value = Double(medicine.count)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Medicine Class (in your case you just did it using `struct` which is also fine; but I created a separate `swift` file):

```
import UIKit
class Medicine{
    var name: String
    var count: Int
    
    init(name: String, count: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.count = count
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't update the data model in the view controller so the functionality will break if you have to scroll.

Comment: thank u @Asol your method works great but can we update medicines array when appending count by stepper. Because i will save array in user defaults

Comment: @МухаммедАралбек maybe you can have another variable that will be responsible for storing `Integer` value of `count`? And you can assign some value to it inside `stepperTapped()` function

Comment: sorry i'm pretty new to programming and i don't understanding what do u mean. can explain it in your answer please

Answer (score 0):

```
var medicalNames: [String] = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
var medicalCount: [Int] = [5,2,7]
```

This is bad design - make this an array of structs instead:

```
struct Medicine { 
   let name: String
   var count: Int
}

let medicines = [
   Medicine(name: "foo", count: 1), Medicine(name: "bar", count: 2)
]
```

Once you've done that, you can easily add a Bool flag like `stepperHidden` which controls whether the stepper is visible in your `configureCell` method. If you want all steppers to be hidden, set all flags to `true` and call `tableView.reloadData()`

Your tableView method would look like this:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "medicalTableViewCell") as! medicalTableViewCell
    let medicine = medicines[indexPath.row]
    cell?.configureCell(with: medicine)
    return cell
}
```

and correspondingly,

```
public func configureCell(_ medicine: Medicine){
    medicalName.text = medicine.name
    medicalCount.text = "\(medicine.count)"
    // stepper.isHidden = medicine.stepperHidden
}
```

Comment: how con i hide steppers by tapping button in VC if it's outlets are in custom table view cell class?

Comment: and how can i use struct to configure cell

Comment: Updated my answer with examples

Comment: what is "Medicine" in public func scope?

Comment: That's the struct I defined as an example. Rename it as you like.

Comment: should i place struct in a cell's class?]

Comment: That's entirely up to you. I tend to put stuff that's used in multiple places into their own file.

Comment: thank u i fully updated cellForRow to static method. so can u explain how to set stepper hidden when button tapped than update value of count when stepped is tapped. i updated my current code as u said

Comment: I already explained how to do that in my answer - "add a Bool flag to the struct"